# My Slowly Changing Dimension in SSIS keeps changing when it's not supposed to

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, scd

I have a SCD transform and when I rerun the same packages 47 records update even though nothing is updated. The only inconsistencies I see is that these 47 records begin with a number 01N, 10A, and etc. Also these all have identical business keys. They all have an ID of 729 for example.

How can I fix this to keep them from updating.

[image]

These are the attributes I have for the SCD. My business key from the previous screen is the ID.

[image]

This is the data. The only discrepancy I notice from this is the similar ID's and those records begin with a numerical value. The columns from the source are similar to the destination. ID is an INT and DESCR is varchar(200)

Comment: We're going to need much more information to go on than what you've provided. How is your SCD defined? Screenshots, table definitions and sample data are going to help.

Comment: Can you look at your question from *our* point of view. You have already diegested your issue and half way thinking... But for us to get a good picture there's more info needed as @billinkc mentioned. What's your table column design? What are you trying to update? Can you show us your `output tab`? Please define which version of SQL Server you are using for the benefit of the community.

Comment: Added additional info to the OP

Comment: +1 for editing and showing what you had done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Yard_Bin_Pile_ID is your SCD business key and the source has multiple rows with the same business key then how would your SCD decide which one to keep? Depending on the requirement you might need to add DW_Begin_Date to your Business Keys.

Comment: That's what I figured. I thought mostly it was a business key issue. I think I'll have to change the business keys to unique id's